# Comparing two files using awk or sed

Tags: file, compare

I have two files...

Lookup is 1285 lines long:

```
cat Lookup.txt 
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

main is 4,838,869 lines long:

```
cat main.txt
abc, USA
pqr, UK
xyz, SA
```

I need to compare lookup and main and then output the matching lines in main to final.txt

Comment: I think you should be much more precise, if you want some help. If you simply want to find which line of `Lookup` are present in `main`, and have no real efficiency concerns, then a single loop over `Lookup` lines and a bit of `grep -x -q`, and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `awk` or `sed` here but `grep`, assuming I am reading your requirements correctly:

```
% grep -f lookup.txt main.txt > final.txt
% cat final.txt 
abc, USA
```